# Shisha Veshishim Umatayim - mi yodeya?

Tags: number, mi-yodeya-series

### Who knows two hundred sixty-six?

*Please cite/link your sources, if possible.*

*At some point between twenty-four hours and a few days from now, I will:*

- *Vote up all interesting, relevant answers.*
- *Accept what I consider the "best" answer.*
- *Move on to the next number.*

*Lazy gematria for today is: סור - "turn away".*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are 266 (some add: and 2/3) amos in a "ris," a measurement used for some halachic purposes (such as the distance you have to go to aid someone whose animal has collapsed under its burden - Bava Metzia 33a).

[R' Y.Y. Keller once suggested to me that the oddity of this figure might be explained by assuming that an amah is exactly 1-1/2 feet (not necessarily the same as the foot in the American system of measurement, though), in which case this makes a nice round figure of 400 such feet.]

Answer (score 3):

[When *Avraham* left *Charan* at the beginning of *Lech L'cha*](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%90%D7%A9%D7%99%D7%AA_%D7%99%D7%91_%D7%93), [*Ever* was 266](http://web.archive.org/web/20090130120032/http://www.math.wustl.edu/~msh210/torah_timeline.html).

Answer (score 2):

חברון = 266  -  A place that is close to every Jewish heart

Comment: Alas, not even most.

Answer (score 2):

In a leap year, *Yom Yerushalayim* is the 266th day in the year if *Heshvan* and *Kislev* are both Mele'im (have 30 days):

*Tishrei*, *Heshvan*, *Kislev* - 30 days each
*Tevet* - 29 days
*Shvat* - 30 days
*Adar A* - 29 days
*Adar B* - 30 days
*Nisan* - 30 days
*Iyar* - 28 days (*Yom Yerushalayim* is on the 28th day of *Iyar*)