# Shiv'a Veshishim Umatayim - mi yodeya?

Tags: number, mi-yodeya-series

### Who knows two hundred sixty-seven?

*Please cite/link your sources, if possible.*

*At some point between twenty-four hours and a few days from now, I will:*

- *Vote up all interesting, relevant answers.*
- *Accept what I consider the "best" answer.*
- *Move on to the next number.*

*Anyone got something related to 800 / 3?*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://www.ushmm.org/wlc/en/article.php?ModuleId=10005201

> On Kristallnacht November 9-10, 1938 rioters destroyed **267**
>   synagogues throughout Germany, Austria, and the Sudetenland.

Answer (score 2):

The last day of Chanuka (Zos Chanuka) is 267 days after Rosh Chodesh Nisan, when Cheshvan has 29 days.

Answer (score 1):

Stealing [an answer of Alex's](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/9513), I'll note that a *ris* is (when rounded to the nearest *ama*) 267 *ama* according to some. See that answer for details.

Answer (score 1):

267 days after the establishment of the State of Israel the last Jews were freed from the detention camps in Cyprus.

http://gumpertdrucker.com/id9.html

Answer (score 1):

Two hundred sixty-seven is the simon in OC which deals with davenning on erev Shabbos. 
There is a view that the world is destined to last 7000 years, the last 1000 years corresponding to the Shabbos of creation. 
A letter in last week’s HaModia pointed out in the name of Harav Nosson Wachtfogel ztz”l that we have just passed (4th Av) the time of Mincha Gedolah (the time from when one can daven mincha) of the erev Shabbos of creation (see part of http://chatzos.com/rabbinic-sources). So 267 is appropriate now.